# How append some info into StringFileInfo or manifest of Setup.exe

Tags: inno-setup

I need insert guid in all my installers for detecting them editions(types and etc) before install.

I searched way how do it by legal way by scripts, but i do not found way to append some info to StringFileInfo or insert my manifest into Setup.exe.

I tried manually change resources of Setup.exe(i used Resource Hacker and my tool), but changes resources corrupting Setup.exe.

How i can resolve my task?

**Exact description:**

I have app.exe and setup.exe(that installing app.exe). In resources of app.exe i have GUID(in VersionInfo -> StringFileInfo -> VALUE "GUID", "123456"). Now i want have same GUID in setup.exe. But i can not found how it do.

**For what i want it:**

I need detect what setup.exe is installer of app.exe

Comment: Do you mean that you want to modify existing (already compiled) installer .exe file with the GUIDs? OR can you re-compile the installer with the GUIDs?

Comment: Change(already compiled) installer.exe or set guid at compile time(not necessarily both methods). In result i want have installer.exe with GUID in resources.

Comment: I read topic.Are there methods other than signing?

Comment: Did you check the other link?

Comment: I edited answer. Hope it help

Comment: It does not explain, why do you need it in the resources. What's wrong about storing it to a file, as the second link shows?